# How to show Fiscal week from week 1 to current__week - 1?

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I'm having a trouble to return the data of a table from the beginning to the "current_week - 1".

So this table contains data of 3 years from 2020 to 2022, and each year has 52 fiscal weeks. I need to conduct a report each week with the data from 202001 to "current-week - 1".

Example:

- Right now is the fiscal week 35 of 2022, then my report needs to return the data of fiscal week 1 of 2020 to the fiscal week 34 of 2022, not 35.

This is my Bigquery SQL code to return everything:

```
select  

FSCL_WK_END_DT As Last_Date_Of_FSCL_WK,
FSCL_YR, 
FSCL_WK_NBR,
FSCL_YR_WK_KEY_VAL As FSCL_YR_WK_NBR,  


from    data-table
group by 1,2,3,4
```

This is how I tried to filter out the current week and failed badly:

```
select  

FSCL_WK_END_DT As Last_Date_Of_FSCL_WK,
FSCL_YR, 
FSCL_WK_NBR,
FSCL_YR_WK_KEY_VAL As FSCL_YR_WK_NBR,  


from    data-table
Where FSCL_WK_NBR < (current.Cast(FSCL_WK_NBR as integer) - 1)
group by 1,2,3,4
```

Thank you for your help everyone,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exclude the current week. To do this I would first get the `MAX()` (most recent) fiscal week and year.

```
-- get the most recent year-week combo
WITH max_year_month AS (
SELECT
MAX(FSCL_YR_WK_KEY_VAL) AS most_recent_week_year
FROM
data-table)

-- get all the data EXCEPT the most recent week and year
SELECT  
FSCL_WK_END_DT As Last_Date_Of_FSCL_WK,
FSCL_YR, 
FSCL_WK_NBR,
FSCL_YR_WK_KEY_VAL As FSCL_YR_WK_NBR,  
FROM
data-table
WHERE
FSCL_YR_WK_KEY_VAL IS NOT IN (SELECT most_recent_week_year FROM max_year_month)
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

I have made a couple of assumptions here so let me know if this does not work and I shall tweak it.